# Middle east & Africa map

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying to find a module for the middle east & Africa map to allow me to click a country and show a popup text depending on the country I click or apoint, this to be used on joomla 2.5.
any body can help with a name of such plugin or a module?

Answer (score 0):

ZHGoogle Map is good, it will allow you to set the initial extent of the map (so to Africa & the Middle East) as well as add points with the popup information that you'd like to show.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/maps-a-weather/maps-a-locations/maps/16900

Hope this helps